# Having Issue with form

Tags: html, submit

How can i submit form using `Enter key`

I am able to submit form using `button click`

Here is my code :

```
<form role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="leave_days">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="txt_catname" id="txt_catename" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Category Name" />
        </div>  
    </div>   
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <button type="button" data-style="expand-right" id="btn_reg" class="btn btn-info ladda-button">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got answer

```
$("#leave_days").keyDown(function(e)){
                var fromto = $("#txt_catename").val();
                var key = e.which;
                if (key == 13) {
                    if(fromto ==""){
                        alert("Please Enter Category Name");
                        document.getElementById('txt_catename').focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(fromto !=""){

                    $.ajax({
                    type : "post",
                    url : "category-mgt/ajax/add-cat.php",
                    data : "category="+fromto,
                    success : function(data) {
                        //alert(data); return false;
                        if (data==1) {  
                            alert('Category Added'); 
                            $('#leave_days').trigger("reset");
                            $('#dataTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();                          
                        }else if(data==2){
                            alert('Category Allready Exist'); 
                            $('#leave_days').trigger("reset");
                        } else {
                            alert('something is going wrong please check this..');
                            return false;
                            //location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                });

              }
                return false;
            }               
        });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<button type="button" data-style="expand-right" id="btn_reg" class="btn btn-info ladda-button">
```

`type="button"`will not submit a form on enter
 `type="submit"`  so it will submit form on enter

```
 type="submit"
```

Comment: but also refresh page

Comment: @VijayAstound, if you don't want to refresh the page, you don't want to "submit" the form; you want to use Ajax to POST the contents of the form to the server.
Using vanilla Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest or using jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener to your input to check for the correct keycode in Javascript. Notice the onkeydown-attribute added to your input

HTML:

```
<form role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="leave_days">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="txt_catname" id="txt_catename" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Category Name" onkeydown="checkForEnter(this, event);" />
            </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <button type="button" data-style="expand-right" id="btn_reg" class="btn btn-info ladda-button">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

On keycode 13, which is enter, get the form and submit it.

Javascript:

```
function checkForEnter(element, event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) // 13 is enter
        document.getElementById("leave_days").submit();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8L5t119L/

OR just change your button to a submit input inside the form tags, like this:

```
<input type="submit" data-style="expand-right" id="btn_reg" class="btn btn-info ladda-button" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: i dont want to refresh page,in your code page refreshed

Comment: @VijayAstound, if you don't want to refresh the page, you don't want to "submit" the form; you want to use Ajax to POST the contents of the form to the server.
Using vanilla Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest or using jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var makeAllFormSubmitOnEnter = function () {
            $('form input, form select').live('keypress', function (e) {
                if (e.which && e.which == 13) {
                    $(this).parents('form').submit();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        };

        makeAllFormSubmitOnEnter();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why he needs javascript ?  i dont think there is any need to js for that

Answer (score 0):

Add the following script in your code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txt_catename').keypress(function (e) {
          if (e.which == 13) {
            $("#leave_days").submit();
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why he needs javascript ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, so even we have `type="button"` if we put some value in the text box and hit enter key so form won't get submitted.